# Pwnable: Process has its own home directory

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow, shellcode, unix

I recently started to do the [pwnable.tw](https://pwnable.tw/) challenges.  I have no problem understanding the actual buffer-overflow and shellcode injection.
However, after the shell is spawned, the flag is read from /home/start/flag (with "start" being the name of the binary file).

Obviously, this directory does not exist in my filesystem.  So my questions are:

- Why is there a virtual home directory for the process?
- How did the program manage to "put" files into this directory?

The process of spawning a shell and `cd`-ing into the virtual home directory (which appears to exist) can be seen here: https://sreelakshmip.wordpress.com/2017/06/05/write-up-start-pwnable-tw/

Comment: That writeup shows them running the exploit against the challenge server, where I'm sure that directory actually exists. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: To be honest, I did not realize that the exploit is run against the server.  I feel very, very stupid.  Thanks for clearing it up to me!

Comment: no problem, welcome to the site!